# Disable configurable product attribute value (radio button) if not available

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

Thanks in advance for any kind of help in this problem.|
I have requirements where I need to display radio button instead of drop down for configurable products. To achieve this i changes the configurable.phtml file (in my custom module).
here is the updated code;

```
<?php $_product    = $this->getProduct();
$_attributes =Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getAllowAttributes());
 if ($_product->isSaleable() && count($_attributes)):?>
<dl>
<?php foreach($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
    <dt><label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_attribute->getLabel() ?></label></dt>

    <div class="input-box">
        <?php $configs = $this->getRegularConfig($_attribute->getData('attribute_id')) ?>
        <?php //foreach($configs['attributes'] as $config):?>
            <?php foreach($configs['options'] as $value):?>
                <dd class="<?php if ($_attribute->decoratedIsLast){?>last<?php }?> <?php echo $this->getCssClass($_attribute->getLabel(), $value['label']); ?>">
                <label class="label-radio-configurable" id="<?php echo (float)$value['price'] + (float) $_product->getPrice();?>">
                <input type="radio" name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]"
                        id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>"
                        class="validate-custom-configurable"
                        value="<?php echo $value['id']?>"/>
                    <?php echo $value['label']?><!-- (+ $<?php printf("%.2f", $value['price'])?>)-->
                </label>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        <?php //endforeach;?>
         </dd>
    </div>
    <p class="fclear"></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</dl>
<?php endif;?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
    document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
        var customValidation = false;
        var priceFormat = <?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getPriceFormat(); ?>;
        $$('.validate-custom-configurable').each(function(el){
            el.observe('click',function(event){
                // get the highest price
                var $price = el.parentNode.id;
                jQuery('.validate-custom-configurable:checked').each(function(){
                    $price = ($price > jQuery(this).parent().attr('id')) ? $price : jQuery(this).parent().attr('id');
                });
                $$('span .price').each(function(elmn){
                    elmn.update(formatCurrency(parseFloat($price), priceFormat)).innerHTML;
                });
            });
        });
        Validation.addAllThese([
            ['validate-custom-configurable', 'This is a required field.', function(v) {
                $$('.validate-custom-configurable').each(function(el){
                    if (el.checked) {
                        customValidation = true;
                    }
                });
                return customValidation;
            }]
        ]);
    });
</script>
```

And the `getRegularConfig()` function looks like this

```
public function getRegularConfig($attribute_id=0)
{
    $attributes = array();
    $options = array();
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
    foreach ($this->getAllowProducts() as $product) {
        $productId  = $product->getId();

        foreach ($this->getAllowAttributes() as $attribute) {
            $productAttribute = $attribute->getProductAttribute();
            $attributeValue = $product->getData($productAttribute->getAttributeCode());
            if (!isset($options[$productAttribute->getId()])) {
                $options[$productAttribute->getId()] = array();
            }

            if (!isset($options[$productAttribute->getId()][$attributeValue])) {
                $options[$productAttribute->getId()][$attributeValue] = array();
            }
            $options[$productAttribute->getId()][$attributeValue][] = $productId;
        }
    }

    $this->_resPrices = array(
        $this->_preparePrice($this->getProduct()->getFinalPrice())
    );

    foreach ($this->getAllowAttributes() as $attribute) {
        $productAttribute = $attribute->getProductAttribute();
        $attributeId = $productAttribute->getId();
        $info = array(
           'id'        => $productAttribute->getId(),
           'code'      => $productAttribute->getAttributeCode(),
           'label'     => $attribute->getLabel(),
           'options'   => array()
        );

        $optionPrices = array();
        $prices = $attribute->getPrices();
        if (is_array($prices)) {
            foreach ($prices as $value) {
                if(!$this->_validateAttributeValue($attributeId, $value, $options)) {
                    continue;
                }

                $info['options'][] = array(
                    'id'    => $value['value_index'],
                    'label' => $value['label'],
                    'price' => $this->_preparePrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent']),
                    'products'   => isset($options[$attributeId][$value['value_index']]) ? $options[$attributeId][$value['value_index']] : array(),
                );
                $optionPrices[] = $this->_preparePrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent']);
                //$this->_registerAdditionalJsPrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent']);
            }
        }
        /**
         * Prepare formated values for options choose
         */
        foreach ($optionPrices as $optionPrice) {
            foreach ($optionPrices as $additional) {
                $this->_preparePrice(abs($additional-$optionPrice));
            }
        }
        if($this->_validateAttributeInfo($info)) {
           $attributes[$attributeId] = $info;
        }
    }
    /*echo '<pre>';
    print_r($this->_prices);
    echo '</pre>';die();*/

    $_request = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getRateRequest(false, false, false);
    $_request->setProductClassId($this->getProduct()->getTaxClassId());
    $defaultTax = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getRate($_request);

    $_request = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getRateRequest();
    $_request->setProductClassId($this->getProduct()->getTaxClassId());
    $currentTax = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getRate($_request);

    $taxConfig = array(
        'includeTax'        => Mage::helper('tax')->priceIncludesTax(),
        'showIncludeTax'    => Mage::helper('tax')->displayPriceIncludingTax(),
        'showBothPrices'    => Mage::helper('tax')->displayBothPrices(),
        'defaultTax'        => $defaultTax,
        'currentTax'        => $currentTax,
        'inclTaxTitle'      => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Incl. Tax'),
    );

    $config = array(
        'attributes'        => $attributes,
        'template'          => str_replace('%s', '#{price}', $store->getCurrentCurrency()->getOutputFormat()),
        'basePrice'         => $this->_registerJsPrice($this->_convertPrice($this->getProduct()->getFinalPrice())),
        'oldPrice'          => $this->_registerJsPrice($this->_convertPrice($this->getProduct()->getPrice())),
        'productId'         => $this->getProduct()->getId(),
        'chooseText'        => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Choose an Option...'),
        'taxConfig'         => $taxConfig,
    );

    if($attribute_id && isset($config['attributes'][$attribute_id])){
        return $config['attributes'][$attribute_id];
    }

    return $config;
}
```

Now what i want is to be able to disable the options values (radio buttons) that are not available for current selection as magento do by default.
Thanks again.